# Image from Google Places Requires Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-places-api

I'm experiencing what I think may be a caching or asynchronous error, but I'm not sure.

Essentially, I have a javascript function to grab the Google Places image for a place the user has inputted.

Here's that function:

```
function getInitialImage(placeIdentifier) {

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));

    request = {placeId: ""+placeIdentifier+""};

service.getDetails(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(status);
    return;

  } else {

      photoUrl = result.photos[0].getUrl({maxWidth: 300});
      sessionStorage.setItem("photoUrl", photoUrl);
      htmlAttr = result.photos[0].html_attributions;
      sessionStorage.setItem("htmlAttr", htmlAttr);
  }

})

photoUrl = sessionStorage.getItem("photoUrl");
htmlAttr = sessionStorage.getItem("htmlAttr");

return {
    photoUrl: photoUrl,
    htmlAttr: htmlAttr
}; 

}
```

This is how I'm calling and using the function on my "main" page:

```
placeIdent = "<?php echo $placeID?>"; 

  console.log(placeIdent);

  photoUrl = "";

  var results; 

  results = getInitialImage(placeIdent);

  photoUrl = results.photoUrl;

  var randStringForUrl = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

  photoUrl = photoUrl + '?' + randStringForUrl;

  htmlAttr = results.htmlAttr; 

  console.log(photoUrl);
```

I'm then updating the source of the image in my page like this:

```
<img id="displayImage" style="height: 200px"></img>
            <script>document.getElementById('displayImage').src = photoUrl
;</script>
```

Note: `console.log(placeIdent)` displays what I would expect - the user's updated placeID, but for some reason `console.log(photoUrl)` is displaying the "old" photoUrl (from a previous request). This is resolved if I manually refresh the page.

Also note, from some previous research I determined that the image may be cached so I appended the URL with `'?' + randStringForUrl` in an effort to avoid caching.

Any thoughts on why `photoUrl` and subsequently the image are not updating until I refresh, even though the `placeIdent` (i.e. Google PlaceID) is updating?

Thank you!!

Comment: how are you making subsequent calls to `getInitialImage(..)` for it to refresh image?

Comment: @82Tuskers, I'm currently not. I'm just clicking refresh in my browser. How do you suggest I make the subsequent call (to essentially mimic page refresh)? All other variables are displaying fine upon refresh (and before refresh).

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution for any other newbies. I ended up using a timeout function:

```
window.onload = function() {

      setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.getElementById('displayImage').src = photoUrl;
      }, 200);
}
```

Which did the trick. My html code has a placeholder loading gif, which is updated 200 milliseconds after page load.

HTML:

```
    <div style="height: 250px;"><img src="images/loading.gif" id="displayImage"></img></div>
```

Hope this helps someone!